# Why am i getting "error: expression is not assignable" for combining increment operators

Tags: c++, increment, lvalue, post-increment, pre-increment

I am trying to concatenate post and pre-increment operators. I see that for some combinations involving post operators, I get the unassignable error. Is it because the post operator will be evaluated once the j's value is defined. can anyone give me a deeper understanding of this?

I am trying these weird scenarios as I am trying to get better in c++. If there is any way to learn better. It would be really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // This works
    j = (++i)++;
    std::cout << "J is: " << j << "\n";

    // This doesn't
    j = ++(i++);
    std::cout << "J is: " << j << "\n";

    // This does
    j = (i++);
    std::cout << "J is: " << j << "\n";

    // This doesn't
    j = (i++)++;
    std::cout << "J is: " << j << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the prefix operator ++ returns an lvalue while the postfix operator ++ returns an rvalue.

So for example you may write (many pluses of an even number)

```
j = ++++++++i;
```

but you may write only (only two pluses)

```
j = i++;
```

From the C++17 Standard ((postfix) 8.5.1.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The value of a postfix ++ expression is the **value** of its operand....

And ((prefix) 8.5.2.2 Increment and decrement)

> 1 ... The result is the updated operand; it is an **lvalue**...

Relative to your question consider one more interesting difference between post-increment and pre-increment. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 10, 20 };

    int *p = a;

    std::cout << p++[0] << '\n';

    p = a;

    std::cout << ++++p[0] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10
12
```

The difference is that the subscript operator is defined through using the postfix expression.

So this expression `p++[0]` is equivalent to `( p++ )[0]`

While this expression `++++p[0]` is equivalent to `++++( p[0] )`